# Datagram receive method not receiving data in java

Tags: java

I am trying to communicate to a network device via UDP protocol  to read different values. The device writes values to port 11104. I just want to connect to device via UDP on this port and want to read the values. For this, i have written below code but it's not working. (I checked IP and Port number are correct).

```
public class GetDeviceResponseClass{

        public static void main(String[] args){
             int deviceport = 11104;   
             String deviceipaddress_str ="xxx.xx.xx.xxx";
             byte[] rcvdata = new byte[1024];    
             InetAddress deviceipaddress = InetAddress.getByName(deviceipaddress_str);
             DatagramSocket rcvsocket = new DatagramSocket();
             rcvsocket.connect(deviceipaddress,deviceport);
             DatagramPacket rcvpacket = new DatagramPacket(rcvdata,rcvdata.length);
             rcvsocket.receive(rcvpacket);//here it is getting stuck
             String response = new String(rcvdata,0,rcvpacket.getLength());
             System.out.println("response = "+response);
             rcvsocket.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: How is this code not working?  What behavior and output are you getting?  What output do you expect/desire?

Comment: It's working upto connect method in the code then its getting stuck (not proceeding further) and not giving any error message as well. Expected output format is {somevalues}.

Comment: You need to bind the socket to port 11104.

Comment: And probably *not* connect it, unless you're certain the device is broadcasting *from* port 11104.

Comment: And I suggest it is working past the connect, up to the `receive()` method, where it blocks.